# Batch String Manipulation

Tags: string, batch-file

I am trying to write a batch program that writes more code based on what the user inputs. I am stuck on the string manipulation, as "!", ">", "&", and "%" all need to be escapeded before they are to be outputted to other files. This is what I have so far:

```
@echo off
set /p code=
set newcode=%code:^%=^%%,^>=^^>,!=^^!,^&=^^&%
echo %newcode%>>file.bat
```

All this escapinging escaped stuff is making my brain hurt, so can you please help me?

Thanks!

Comment: PLease explain what you intend to use this, or why you want to escape all these characters. DO you simply redirect this to a file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use delayed expansion in your case, as delayed expansion needs no further escaping for the content.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set /p code=
echo(!code!
```

The `echo(` is for safe text output, even if the text is empty or is something like `/?`.

To the comment of @foxidrive:
When delayed expansion is enabled, then exclamation marks `!` are altered, when they are *visible* **before** the delayed expansion is done, but the **expanded content** of delayed expanded variables will never be altered.

```
@echo off
set "var=Hello!"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion    
echo "!var!" "Hello!"
```

This will result to: `"Hello!" "Hello"`

Comment: It needs to be changed for `!` jeb.

Comment: @foxidrive What needs to be changed? I don't understand your statement

Comment: I thought delayed expansion would alter `!` characters but it doesn't.  Mea Culpa.

Comment: @foxidrive Yes it's a bit confusing, I added a sample

Answer (score 3):

Since you haven't explained clearly what you are trying to do with the input, I am assuming you are trying to get the user to type something and then for that to be entered into a file. If that is the case te utilise `copy` in combination with `con`

```
@echo off
Echo Enter ^^Z (Ctrl + Z) and return it to end input
copy con file.txt
```

And that will allow the user to type WHATEVER they want, and it to be put in a file to be examined. Otherwise you're gonna have a lot of fun (And trouble) dealing with all the escaping you're gonna have to do (Rather ironic wasn't that?).

Mona.